the PDF of the empirical distribution
Say I have n samples $x_1,...,x_n \sim F$ where $F$ is a continuous distribution on $\mathbb R$.
The Empirical Distribution Function gives us an estimation for the CDF of $F$.
I am trying to understand how the corresponding pdf will look.
I see in the question Empirical PDF from Empirical CDF that someone answered, that the PDF in this case will simply put a probability mass of $1/N$ at each data point $x_i$.
But if we are in the continuous case, we cannot simply define that the pdf at each point is $1/N$ and zero elsewhere, since this will give probability 0 to everything.
The pdf is the derivative of the CDF, but in our case the CDF is a step function and therefore doesn't have a derivative in the interesting points (only has a derivative of 0).
So how does the PDF look in this case?

I presume you ask for the PDF of the empirical distribution, rather than the PDF of the empirical PDF which, as a (step) function over $\mathbb R$, does not have a density.

There is no standard PDF estimate that follows from the empirical CDF, since it cannot be differentiated in a useful manner, being a step function.

@Xi'an Thanks that makes sense.
